# desc = name must be valid as a dns name component

Tags: docker, dns, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am trying to deploy minio to my docker cluster, and I am basing my docker-compose script from the auto generated one found on minio.io

The problem is that when trying to deploy it to my cluster I am getting the error `desc = name must be valid as a dns name component`, which after searching the web abit seems to mostly be related to container names containing `.`. However mine doesn't, so I am wonder what is causing this error, as I am not seeing anything that would not be a valid dns URL(I am most likely wrong)

The docker compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
 minio1:
  image: minio/minio
  volumes:
   - minio-data1:/export
  ports:
   - "9001:9000"
  networks:
   - minio_distributed
  environment:
   MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: <ACCESS>
   MINIO_SECRET_KEY: <SECRET>
  deploy:
   restart_policy:
    delay: 10s
    max_attempts: 10
    window: 60s
  command: server http://minio1/export http://minio2/export http://minio3/export http://minio4/export 

 minio2:
  image: minio/minio
  volumes:
   - minio-data2:/export
  ports:
   - "9002:9000"
  networks:
   - minio_distributed
  environment:
   MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: <ACCESS>
   MINIO_SECRET_KEY: <SECRET>
  deploy:
   restart_policy:
    delay: 10s
    max_attempts: 10
    window: 60s
  command: server http://minio1/export http://minio2/export http://minio3/export http://minio4/export 

 minio3:
  image: minio/minio
  volumes:
   - minio-data3:/export
  ports:
   - "9003:9000"
  networks:
   - minio_distributed
  environment:
   MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: <ACCESS>
   MINIO_SECRET_KEY: <SECRET>
  deploy:
   restart_policy:
    delay: 10s
    max_attempts: 10
    window: 60s
  command: server http://minio1/export http://minio2/export http://minio3/export http://minio4/export 

 minio4:
  image: minio/minio
  volumes:
   - minio-data4:/export
  ports:
   - "9004:9000"
  networks:
   - minio_distributed
  environment:
   MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: <ACCESS>
   MINIO_SECRET_KEY: <SECRET>
  deploy:
   restart_policy:
    delay: 10s
    max_attempts: 10
    window: 60s
  command: server http://minio1/export http://minio2/export http://minio3/export http://minio4/export 

volumes:
  minio-data1:
  minio-data2:
  minio-data3:
  minio-data4:

networks:
 minio_distributed:
  driver: overlay
```

So there is obviously something that I am not understanding propperly

Comment: Can you provide the commad that you are using to deploy?

Comment: I am deploying it using the GUI in portainer... you think that might be the problem?

Comment: Try to deploy it from the command line `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml`

Comment: huh, seems rather odd that it wouldn't work in portainer. But cli worked fine, so thank you!

Answer (score 11):

When creating the stack in portainer, the stack name is used to create the networks names (`<stack_name>_<network_name>`). 
So if it contains unauthorized chars (like `.` or space), then the network name will get refused. 
Name your stack without any special char and you can deploy it.

Comment: Also, it cannot end with an underscore (`_`) as I found out today. Hope that saves someone else's time 

Comment: Awesome. Mine had a dot in the container name and hence it failed. The funny part is that if I run it as a normal container, it takes the name. If I ran it as a part of a swarm, it fails.

Comment: @akki actually: end or start :( .. with `-` or `_`. but they are ok in the middle of string.

Answer (score 1):

If you work both OS Windows and Linux simultaneously and you use bash scripts check out a kind of line endings. Windows adds '\r' at the end of each line and it causes mentioned error in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in visual studio, the docker-compose.yml services would be equal than docker-compose.override.yml... In my case I rename the services' names in docker-compose.yml but not in docker-compose.override.yml.